# Caused by: java.awt.print.PrinterException: No print service found. Windows Server 2008 - Java

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to print a document using glassfish 3.1.2, JReports 4.7.1 and I'm having this issue:

In my computer I can print with no problem, everything goes fine. But after I make deploy of my aplication to my client's server, if I try to print I get this message error. Does anybody have passed through this, or could help me to solve it?

Windows Server 2008 and my computer is windows 7.
The printer is set as defaut, the spooler is working, I already restarted it, I tested my procedures, connections...
Below the stacktrace:

Thanks!

```
    [#|2012-10-30T08:30:59.293-     0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_Thr    eadID=171;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error printing     report.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPages(JRPrinterAWT.java:197)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPages(JRPrinterAWT.java:84)
at    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.printPages(JasperPrintManager.java:197)
at  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.printPage(JasperPrintManager.java:136)
at br.com.hrtech.hrprodutos.model.command.Buscador.imprimirLista(Buscador.java:138)
at br.com.hrtech.hrprodutos.controller.CBuscador.actImprimirLista(CBuscador.java:570)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
at   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56)
at       com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at     javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at   com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipe line.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at  com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.awt.print.PrinterException: No print service found.
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1305)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1277)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPages(JRPrinterAWT.java:192)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Could [this](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5024816) be relevant?

Comment: I don't think so. This bug reffers to java 1.4 and applets, this is not my case. I'm using java 1.6 and a normal webapplication. Also, this bug was fixed in 1.5.
"The output of the above commands seems reasonable and I have found
the problem which is actually bug 4930594, fixed in 1.5"


Could my problem be something  about permission?